How much of a foundation wall can be exposed without risking instability?
To prevent this clay pushing against the house wall I'm making this egress window.  The total length is about 40 feet. Is this too much to leave unfilled or not?



Is there a basement behind that insulation board?

A foundation wall isn't going to fail because there is no earth pressing against its side.  You can excavate as much as you want.
Just dont excavate under the foundation.

Well, a poured concrete foundation won't, but other types of foundations will fail when you excavate near them, eg field stone. It can also happen with cinder block foundations if there's outward pressure, as happens when a house settles unevenly
